# React Native: Cannot read propert 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, registration, jsx

I have been trying to building a registration app and am running into some issues in the final stages when trying to submit the new values to the server.

Here is my script:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactNative from 'react-native';
import { FormLabel, FormInput,Button,Text } from 'react-native-elements'
import { AppRegistry,TextInput,View,StyleSheet,length} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import AccountFields from './emailandpass'
import axios from 'axios';

let styles = {}

class NameFields extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      email:'',
      password:'',
      first:'',
      last:'',
      dob:''
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    console.log("nextProps",nextProps);
  }

  handlePress(event){
    var Url = "http://10.68.14.170:8080";
    // console.log("values in register handler",role);
    var self = this;

    //To be done:check for empty values before hitting submit
    if(this.state.first.length>0 && this.state.last.length>0 && this.state.email.length>0 && this.state.password.length>0 && this.state.dob.length>0)
      {
      var payload={
      "first": this.state.first,
      "last":this.state.last,
      "email":this.state.email,
      "password":this.state.password,
      "dob":this.state.dob
      }
      axios.post(Url+'/useraccount/signup',payload)
     .then(function (response) {
       console.log(response.data);
       if(response.data.code === 200){
        <Text>
          'Tal-ostja'
        </Text>
       }
       else{
         console.log("some error ocurred",response.data.code);
       }
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error);
     });
    }
    else{
      alert("Input field value is missing");
    }
   }

  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <FormLabel
          containerStyle={styles.labelContainerStyle}>Email</FormLabel>
        <FormInput
          ref='form2'
          containerRef='containerRefYOYO'
          textInputRef='textInputRef'
          placeholder='Please enter your email address...'
          onChangeText = {(event,newValue) =>this.setState({email:newValue})}
        />
        <FormLabel containerStyle={styles.labelContainerStyle}>Password</FormLabel>
        <FormInput 
          ref='form1' 
          placeholder='Please create a password...'
          onChangeText ={(event,newValue) =>this.setState({email:newValue}) }
        />
        <FormLabel
          containerStyle={styles.labelContainerStyle}>Name</FormLabel>
        <FormInput
          ref='form2'
          containerRef='containerRefYOYO'
          textInputRef='textInputRef'
          placeholder="What's your name ?"
          onChangeText = {(event,newValue) =>this.setState({first:newValue})}
        />
        <FormLabel containerStyle={styles.labelContainerStyle}>Surname</FormLabel>
        <FormInput 
          ref='form1' 
          placeholder="What's your last name ?" 
          onChangeText = {(event,newValue) =>this.setState({last:newValue})} 
        />
        <FormLabel containerStyle={styles.labelContainerStyle}>Date of Birth</FormLabel>
        <FormInput 
          ref='form1' 
          placeholder='YYYY-MM-DD'
          onChangeText = {(event,newValue) =>this.setState({dob:newValue})}
        />
        <Button title="Submit" onPress={(event) => this.handlePress(event)}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = NameFields
```

As you can see, I am first defining the `this.state` within the constructor then defining the `handlePress()` method which is called under it within the JSX function which creates the form.

Form some reason, upon pressing submit I am encountering the following error:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.
>
> `t.value`
>
> namefields.js:33:24
>
> `Object.onPress`
>
> namefields.js:102:56

which is perplexing me because, as I said, I defined the state in the constructor and within the form function called for `newValue` to be input.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments that will be passed to the `onChangeText` handler do not include the `event` object. From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.48/docs/textinput.html#onchangetext):

> **`onChangeText` function**
>
> Callback that is called when the text input's text changes. Changed text is passed as an argument to the callback handler.

So change:

```
onChangeText = {(event,newValue) =>this.setState({email:newValue})}
```

to:

```
onChangeText = {(newValue) =>this.setState({email:newValue})}
```

... everywhere where you have `onChangeText =`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Now the if is never being entered and the else is always being executed, 
displaying "Input field value is missing" even though all fields were filled correctly.
Any ideas @trincot ?

Comment: You never set the password field in the `onChangeText` handler. You have `email` twice in the `onChangeText` handlers. The second one should be `password`.

Comment: Thanks @trincot, have been looking at this file for too long.

Answer (score 0):

Bind handlePress in the constructor:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handlePress = this.handlePress.bind(this);
    this.state={
      email:'',
      password:'',
      first:'',
      last:'',
      dob:''
    }
}
```

Comment: @slacerda7 still got the same problem after implementing in constructor